# Stack at getting elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html elements from which I have to get some specific texts,
example "John Doe"

I'm a newbie in javascript but have been playing with getElementById etc but I can't seem to get this one right.

```
 <div id="name">
    <p><span id="nameheading">name:&nbsp;</span> John Doe</p>
 </div>

Bellow is What I have tried:

function askInformation()
{

   var nameHeading = document.getElementById("nameheading");
   var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName("p").item(0).innerHTML ;
   var name = paragraph[4];

   console.log(name); // prints letter (n)
}
```

I need help please

Comment: `paragraph[4]` is the 5th letter of the string in `paragraph` (`"<span id..."`)

Comment: `nameHeading.innerHTML.charAt(4); // e`. Are you sure your DOMContent is loaded? `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', askInformation);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the text following the span in the following:

```
<div id="name">
    <p><span id="nameheading">name:&nbsp;</span> John Doe</p>
 </div>
```

You can use something like:

```
// Get a reference to the span
var span = document.getElementById('nameheading');

// Get the following text
var text = span.nextSibling.data;
```

However that is highly dependent on the internal structure, it may be best to loop over text node children and collect the content of all of them. You may also want to trim leading and trailing white space.

You could also get a reference to the parent DIV and use a function like the following that collects the text children and ignores child elements:

```
// Return the text of the child text nodes of an element,
// but not descendant element text nodes
function getChildText(element) {
  var children = element.childNodes;
  var text = '';
  for (var i=0, iLen=children.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (children[i].nodeType == '3') {
      text += children[i].data;
    }
  }
  return text;
}

var text = getChildText(document.getElementById('name').getElementsByTagName('p')[0]);
```

or more concisely for hosts that support the [*querySelector interface*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/):

```
var text = getChildText(document.querySelector('#name p'));
```

Comment: Great explanation and does the trick as well. Thanx so much. I appreciate your efforts..  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName("p").item(0).innerHTML ;
var name = paragraph.replace('<span id="nameheading">name:&nbsp;</span>','').trim(); // John Doe
```

Comment: Thanx so much..  This method works...  I appreciate your feedback.